# Turning a list into a set - Python

Tags: python, list, set, list-comprehension, typeerror

I wanted to print a set of lines in a file that start with a certain character (here it's "c"), but I get an error whenever I try to convert a list into a set

I have the following code:

```
z = open("test.txt", "r")
wordList = [line.rstrip().split() for line in z if line.startswith(("c"))]
wordList = set(wordList)
print(wordList)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   wordList = set(wordList)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: This "line.rstrip().split() for line in z if line.startswith(("c"))" is a generator expression. Maybe it is case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop the `.split()`, you'll end up with your set of lines.

Comment: Thank you dear sir, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

For efficient look-ups, `set` works with hashable types only. In particular, hashable types must be immutable, that means, they may not be changed after construction. Since you can append elements to and remove elements from a list, it is mutable. In contrast, a `tuple` is fixed after construction and hashable.

Hence, if you really want a set of word sequences, you have to convert the words of each line from a list into a tuple:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as z:
    wordList = set(tuple(line.rstrip().split()) for line in z if line.startswith("c"))
```

---

**Edit:** If you instead want a set of all words in lines starting with "c", use the following:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as z:
    wordList = set(w for line in z if line.startswith("c") for w in line.rstrip().split())
```

Comment: Thanks man, this helped me too!